# Is it possible to add linq to the end of a method that returns rows from a database? I just want to tack on an ORDER BY clause

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, datagrid

```
private void cboEventFilter_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
        ComboBoxItem item = cboEventFilter.SelectedItem as ComboBoxItem;
        
        switch (item.Content)
        {
            case "Date":
                //Original method
                datActiveEvents.ItemsSource = _eventManager.RetrieveActiveEvents();
                //Something like this line commented out

                //datActiveEvents.ItemsSource = _eventManager.RetrieveActiveEvents().OrderBy<EventDateID>;
                break;

            case "Time":
                MessageBox.Show("Time filter selected");
                break;

            case "Name":
                MessageBox.Show("Event Name filter selected");
                break;

            case "Sublocation":
                MessageBox.Show("Sublocation filter selected");
                break;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the return type of `RetrieveActiveEvents()` is an `IEnumerable<T>`, you could use the `OrderBy` LINQ extension method:

```
datActiveEvents.ItemsSource = _eventManager.RetrieveActiveEvents()
    .OrderBy(x => x.EventDateID);
```

If the return type is a non-generic `IEnumerable`, you could use the `Cast` extension method to convert it to an `IEnumerable<T>` before you sort the results:

```
datActiveEvents.ItemsSource = _eventManager.RetrieveActiveEvents()
    .Cast<YourClassWithTheEventDateIDProperty>()    
    .OrderBy(x => x.EventDateID);
```